# Can't assign to object array when fetching data with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have come across a problem that I do not understand while trying to integrate redux toolkit and more specifically RTK Query into my project. All I want to do is fetch an object array from my backend using a query hook, pass this data into my component and alter some of the elements inside the data based on user actions.

I am copying the incoming array so as not to mutate the original.

I can replace entire objects in the array with 'blah' but if I try to alter a single value within one of the objects I get:

`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'title' of object '#<Object>'`

This problem didn't arise when I was using fetch().

I have been stuck on this for days!!!

**apiSlice**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.devUrl }),
  tagTypes: ['categories'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCategories: builder.query({
      query: () => 'categories/includingJobs',
      transformResponse: (response) => response.data.data,
      providesTags: ['categories'],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCategoriesQuery} = apiSlice;
```

**Component**

```
import {
  useGetCategoriesQuery,
} from '../features/api/apiSlice';

const Test = () => {
  const {
    data: categories,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetCategoriesQuery();

  if (isSuccess) {

    let categoriesCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories));

    //This is the line that breaks everything. Why?
    categoriesCopy[0].title = 'new title';
  }

  return <h1>Something rendered</h1>;
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: With that deep copy (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories))`), it should actually work - are you sure it crashes with that code?

Comment: It looks like you're right. I tried to simplify the code for SO but in my project I am using React-beautiful-dnd and trying to modify my object array inside of my onDragEnd function, which is what is not working.

Comment: Well, are you creating a copy there like you do here?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to manage the reordering of columns and cards on a kanban board. The component is wrapped in a <DragDropContext /> which is where handleOnDragEnd gets fired off.

Comment: I can successfully use splice() to reorder the object array but when i then map over it to update a value in each of the objects I get the error. It's strange because this same code was working when I was using fetch.

Comment: I would assume you are creating a shallow copy of the array, not a deep copy - so modifying an array object in there tries to modify a reference to the state. Are you **really** using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` here to create that copy or something else?

Comment: Yes, really! You can see the code on github [here](https://github.com/thomassleeman/banana-skins/blob/0fbb4fe0a7f1fef7abe84155bbeca97f6306d881/frontend/components/Kanban.js#L41).

Comment: Ah, but then you splice `categories[source.index]` in there which is not a copy, but reference to your Redux state. That means that in the for loop, you try to manipulate a direct refetence to your old Redux state.

Comment: Wow. Ok, yeah that fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help. I thought the 3rd param of splice was just being read so it wouldn't matter. Looks like the lesson here is, once you've copied the original array from your state, just leave it alone!

Comment: The other lesson would be to share relevant code early ;) Good that we found it!